# Custom log4j layout in Spark (on YARN) - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, hadoop-yarn

I’m running into a strange issue with trying to use a custom Log4j layout for Spark (1.6.1) on YARN (CDH). The layout is: https://github.com/michaeltandy/log4j-json

If I use a log4j.properties file (supplied with --files) with:

```
log4j.appender.consolejson=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consolejson.target=System.err
log4j.appender.consolejson.layout=uk.me.mjt.log4jjson.SimpleJsonLayout
```

And supply the log4j-json.1.0.jar with `--jars` to `spark-submit`, the driver and executors throw an exception right at the start of the log file:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [uk.me.mjt.log4jjson.SimpleJsonLayout].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uk.me.mjt.log4jjson.SimpleJsonLayout
```

However, a simple spark job that does something like:

```
sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3)).foreach(i => {Class.forName("uk.me.mjt.log4jjson.SimpleJsonLayout")})
```

Doesn’t throw an error. So the class is being loaded, but just not in time for Log4j to use it.

I've tried a few different options trying to get it to work (including it in the YARN application classpath, spark executor classpaths etc) and they all produce the same results. The only thing that seems to work is building a custom spark-assembly with the maven dependency included in `core/pom.xml`. This way, the layout is included in the spark assembly jar, and I get the JSON log output desired.

Is there a classloading issue on Log4j when using `--jars`? I can't imagine why it works with bundling in spark-assembly, but doesn't work with `--jars`.

Comment: have you found a solution?